# $\int_E f d\mu=\int_E f_{|E}d\mu_{|\mathcal S_{|E}}$

Tags: integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Let $(X,\mathcal S,\mu)$ bei a measure space, $E\in \mathcal S$ and $f:X\rightarrow \overline{\mathbb R}$ measurable and not negative.
Show that $\int_E f d\mu=\int_E f_{|E}d\mu_{|\mathcal S_{|E}}.$
I already showed that $f_{|E}:(E,\mathcal S_{|E})\rightarrow(\overline{\mathbb R},\mathscr B(\overline{\mathbb R}))$ is measurable.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Many of this problems have similar solutions: start by taking $f$ as an indicator function, then extend to positive simple functions (positive linear combinations of indicator functions) and then by monotone convergence extend the result further to general nonnegative functions.

Comment: My question is how to show the equality.

Comment: i tried to show it for an indicater function. For $A\in \mathcal S_{|E}\subseteq \mathcal S$ i get $\int_E fd\mu=\mu(E\cap A)$ and $\int_E f_{|E}d\mu_{|\mathcal S_{|E}}=\mu_{|\mathcal S_{|E}}(A\cap E)$. But why are they the same and what if $A\not\in \mathcal S_E$?